# JavaScript рекурсия

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Изучаю JavaScript, рекурсия. Пример из учебника.

**Задача**: возведение числа x в натуральную степень n. В данном примере функция с параметрами (2,3).
**Код:**

```js
function pow(x,n) {
 if (n != 1) {
   return x *= pow(x,n - 1);
 } else {
   return x;
 }
}
alert( pow(2,3)); // 8
```

Не могу разобраться, как работает данная функция. **( x, n)** это ведь всего лишь параметры которые мы передаем, почему здесь в **pow** `return x *= pow(x,n - 1);` что-то происходит и откуда взялся этот **-1**?
 `x *= pow(2,2);` что дальше происходит и почему?

Comment: `a^b = a*(a^(b-1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Разобрался, наглядный разбор данной функции.

Вызываем функцию с параметрами (2,3), т.е. функция имеет данный вид:

```html
function pow(2, 3) {
 if (3 != 1) {
   return 2 *= pow(2, 3 - 1);
 } else {
   return 2;
 }
}
```

- Далее функция(назовем ее внешняя) вызывает сама себя и создает новый уровень вложенности( назовем клон 1 ), (PS внешняя не может завершиться пока не завершатся все внутренние(клоны))
- далее клон 1 вызывает сам себя и создает новый уровень вложенности( назовем клон 2 ),
- далее на клоне 2 срабатывает условие **else**, значит return **x**, и клон 2 возвращает **двойку** клону 1.
- На клоне 1 срабатывает условие **if** т.е. 2 * 2( двойку вернул клон 2) , и результат(четверка) возвращается внешней функции.
- На внешней функции срабатывает условие **if** т.е. 2 * 4( четверку вернул клон 1 ), и возвращает результат(восьмерку ) в alert.

Вот наглядная схема работы данной функции:

[image: javascript рекурсия пример]

Спасибо **Akina** что помог мне разобраться.

Answer (score 5):

Правильно передаём параметры `2, 3`

1. Дальше проверяем `3` не равно `1`, да ---> переходим в блок `if`
2. Возвращаем результат и записываем его в `x`. Тут краткая запись она означает `x = x * результат выполнения функции`.
   Возвращаем какой результат? --> `x` умноженный на результат выполнения функции `pow`, с новыми параметрами. Какими ? `2, 3-1 --> 2, 2`
3. Т.е. функция вызывает, сама себя). И поехали ---->
4. Проверяем теперь уже `2` не равно `1`, да ---> переходим в блок `if`
5. Возвращаем результат. `x` умноженный на `pow(2, 1);`
6. Результат снова записали в х.
7. Проверяем `1 не равно 1` - это условие ложно, т.к.  1=1, значит переходим в блок `else` и просто возвращаем `x`. А там у же накопились значения с предыдущих шагов

Comment: Спасибо! `результат выполнения функции` это видимо и есть `(x,n - 1)`, т..е. на первом шаге `результат выполнения функции`(2,2), как дальше мы можем умножить `x` на функцию? На первом шаге выполняем  `2 *  pow(2,2)` как мы можем умножить на функцию? какой здесь порядок расчетов и какой результат получается?

Comment: на функцию мы не умножаем, интерпритатор (тот кто выполняет код), сначала исполняет функцию, и подставит полученное значение, получится x умножить на 4, например, т.е. умножаем на результат выполнения функции (а это просто число которое вернула функция). функция исполнилась и что то вернула (return - как раз для этого)

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Смотрите. Вы вызываете функцию с параметрами (2,3). Она в свою очередь вызывает вторую копию функции, на сей раз с параметрами (2,2). Та вызовет третью копию, с параметрами (2,1). Третья копия вернёт значение (сработает альтернативная ветка в IF), равное первому параметра, т.е. 2. Вторая копия получит его, продолжит вычисление выражения, умножит 2 на 2 и вернёт в первую копию 4. Та произведёт умножение 2 на 4 и вернёт в основную программу 8.

Comment: @Akina спасибо! ваше объяснение про копии мне помогло понять, хотя до этого я читал достаточно много других объяснений.   Иначе говоря внешняя функция не может выполниться пока не выполнится внутренняя(которую она вызывает). Получается три уровня вложенности; третий останавливается из-за заданного условия `(n != 1)`, и возвращает 2(наш `x`), третий уровень вернул двойку второму, далее второй выполняет `*=`  т. е. умножение на два, второй уровень получает 4 и возвращает первому и первый умножает на два и возвращает 8 в `alert`. Это очень интересно!

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Одна только ремарка. Функция вообще-то содержит серьёзную ошибку. Представьте, что мы имели глупость попросить вычислить `pow(2, 2.5)`... Условие следует изменить, например, на `if (n < 2) {return x *= pow(x,n - 1);} else {return 1;}`. Причём подобная фигня может быть и ненамеренной - например, аргумент может вычисляться выражением как число с плавающей точкой, и вместо ожидаемого, например, 3, у нас получится вторым аргументом какое-нибудь 2.999999997.